# JSONPath Syntax does not work when dot in key's in more than 2 filter fields

Tags: json, kubernetes

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  backupscript:
  service.properties: |
    agent.download.location = /home/bnr
    script.execution.time.in.minutes = 1
```

Need to fetch value in "script.execution.time.in.minutes".

I am using ..-o "jsonpath={.data['service\.properties'].'script\.execution\.time\.in\.minutes'}"

It is giving me empty result.
How do we use the Escape on the end field's filter.

Comment: The content of /data/service.properties is a multi-line string, they are not keys of the yaml document.

Comment: Yea, that is correct. Cool!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I find it helpful when working with jsonpath expressions, to start smaller and build up.

For example, does this work and if so, what does it return?

```
-o "jsonpath={.data['service\.properties']"
```

Then add the next part on.

That being said, I think the problem you're going to run into is that these are not yaml properties, but instead is a string, as indicated by the `|`:

```
  service.properties: |
    agent.download.location = /home/bnr
    script.execution.time.in.minutes = 1
```

So I don't think you're going to be able to use jsonpath alone to query the value of `script.execution.time.in.minutes`.

You can probably do what you want with a combination of jsonpath and awk+sed, something like this:

```
kubectl get pod foo -o jsonpath="{.data['service\.properties']}" | awk -F'=' '$1 ~ /script\.execution\.time\.in\.minutes/ {print $2}' | sed 's/ //'
```

This does the following:

1. Get the service properties using jsonpath
2. Use awk to extract the number from the line that has script.execution.time.in.minutes
3. Use sed to remove spaces

There might be a more elegant way to accomplish this, but hopefully this can at least help you get an idea of one way to do it.

Comment: That was explained very well Brain , thanks.
That is indeed a string.

Now, I am looking for way to patch the CinfigMap's "script.execution.time.in.minutes" to "2".
will appreciate with any help on that as well, please

Comment: Well, instead of using awk, you can just use sed to find `script.execution.time.in.minutes = 1` and replace it with `script.execution.time.in.minutes = 2`. Depending on how consistent your environment is, you may need to use a regular expression to match regardless of spacing.  Something like this might work: `sed 's/script.execution.time.in.minutes\s*=\s*1/script.execution.time.in.minutes = 2/'`

Comment: Got it, it would rather be easy to dump the configmaps yaml file, modify it and patch it, rather than figuring out some way to patch the specific line of the string with JSONpath if at all it is possible at the moment.